# jqgrid search box drop down filter names

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

Good evening to everyone,

I use jqgrid with jsonstring datatype, and i use search box for searching.

This results (and it sounds normal) to a searhbox which has the column names as filters.

Eg

`colNames:['Name','StartDate','EndDate']`

will lead to a drop down in the searchbox with three option values:

Name, StartDate and EndDate

Is there a way to keep Name, StartDate and EndDate as my grid headers, but have different option values in the filter drop down of the searhbox?

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `label` property to define the text of column which will be displayed in the Searching Dialog. For example [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/customColumnNamesInSearchingDialog.htm) uses the following properties

```js
colNames: ["Client", "Date", "Amount", "Tax", "Total",
           "Closed", "Shipped via", "Notes"],
colModel: [
    { name: "name", ..., label: "Client Name" },
    { name: "invdate", ..., label: "Start Date" },
    { name: "amount", ..., label: "Amount without TAX" },
    { name: "tax", ... },
    { name: "total", ..., label: "Total Price" },
    {name: "closed", ..., label: "Is Closed?" },
    {name: "ship_via", ... },
    { name: "note", ... }
],
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much Oleg. I cannot believe how i missed it in the documentation!

Comment: @GeorgeR.: You are welcome! I'm not sure that it is really documented, but I just looked in the source code to see exactly how the options of the select will be built.